# Why can't I print the pointer value that has been initialized while declaring the pointer?

Tags: c

I initialized the pointer with a constant, and I knew its address will be delivered to the pointer. So when I tried to test whether the constant can be print or not, the program crashed. Is that illegal?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int *i = (int *)1;

    printf("The value that i pointer points to is %d\n", *i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not printing the pointer constant, but the content it is pointing to. Your pointer points to the constant address `0x1`, which isn't a valid address, so your program crashes.

Comment: Did you expect any particular output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to think `(int *)1` produces the address where the value 1 is stored. It does not.

When a cast such as `(int *)` is used to convert an integer to a pointer, the result is generally that the value is made into an address.<sup>1</sup>

Thus `int *i = (int *)1;` sets `i` to point to the address 1. Then, when attempting to print `*i`, your program crashed because 1 was not a valid memory address. (Quite commonly, the first page of memory is kept unmapped so that incorrect uses of the null pointer will crash and reveal a problem rather than allowing the program to continue executing with incorrect data.)

To set `i` to point to an `int` with the value 1, you must set it to the address of an `int` object that has the value 1. One way to do this is:

```
int n = 1;
int *i = &n;
```

You can also create an unnamed `int` with the value 1 using a compound literal:

```
int *i = & (int) { 1 };
```

The `(int) { 1 }` creates a compound literal with the value 1, and the `&` takes its address, and then `i` is initialized to that address.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> According to the C standard, the result is implementation-defined. So a compiler could define any result it wants. However, every C compiler I have seen makes the integer value into an address, in one way or another. The resulting address is not necessarily valid to use for accessing an object.

Answer (score 5):

(int *)1; is not a pointer to value 1. but rather the pointer to the memory cell # 1. What you probably want is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int n=1;
   int *i = &n;

    printf("The value that i pointer points to is %d\n", *i);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> printf("The value that i pointer points to is %d\n", *i);
> ```

You try to dereference the pointer `i`, but it's value (the value of the pointer) is some value, you set yourself. Can you guarantee that at address `0x0001` is an integer you own? All you can do with such a pointer is print it's pointer value (not the value it points to):

```
printf("The value of pointer i is %p\n", i);
```